# Getting the lowest price from other table in entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

im working on this website where i bring all the available products on a page. Each of this product has his own ProductDetail(s) with colors, sizes , prices, etc.

I want to display the lowest available price for this product.I use a ViewModel with a list of products and at this moment i dont know how i can get the price to this specific product.Its productsdetails is a list aswell. So somehow i should have to get the lowest price of its ProductDetails.

This is my viewmodel:

```
var model = new ViewModelProductOverview()
        {
            Products = new ProductRepository().GetProductsAvailable(Id, Index, Size),
            Category = new CategoryRepository().Get(Id),
            CurrentPageID = page.HasValue ? page.Value : -1
        };
```

My view:

```
@{
            var i = 0;

            foreach (var product in Model.Products)
            {
                var position = "";
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0: position = "first";
                        break;
                    case 1: position = "second";
                        break;
                    case 2: position = "third";
                        break;
                    default: i = 0; position = "first";
                        break;
                }

            <li class="@position"><a href="@Url.Action("Detail", "Product", new { productseourl = product.Name.ToSeoUrl(Sign.Minus), productid = product.ID })" >
            </a>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @product.Name @product.FabricType.Name
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                            //Its lowest price need to come here
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @product.SubCategory.Name
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                            //Promotion price
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </li>
                i++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just a little bit of code (outline of the classes) would make this a lot easier to answer.

Comment: i have updated with code samples.

Comment: The ASPX isn't going to help much.

Answer (score 1):

Basically,

```
 var minPrice = allProducts.Details.Select(d => d.Price).Min();

 var cheapestDetail = allProducts.Details.OrderBy(d => d.Price).First();
```

Comment: Problem is , i need to get this information for every Product in the list.

Comment: Problem is we don't know your classes.

Comment: What code do you wanna see exactly? My model? I use repositorys for each entity to get my collections.

Comment: Yes, (an abbreviated version of) the model classes involved.

Comment: Well i have several products wich are from a specific category, each product has many productdetails, each with its own price. In the product entity i have ProductDetail as navigation property and ProductDetail has ID, ColorID, SizeID, ProductID and price. So i wanna show all products on a page but with the price of its lowest productdetail.hope this helps.